# Raspberry Pi 3 freezes - triggered by rsyslogd?

Tags: raspberry-pi3

My Raspberry Pi keeps freezing after a few hours of activity. It often happens at exactly 17 minutes past the hour so I'm suspecting this might be related to a cron job. When I look into /var/log/syslog after rebooting, I see that each freeze comes right after a flurry of activity that always starts with this line (You can see the entire log output following that line, all the way to the point a freezing at https://pastebin.com/m1dmferU):

```
Aug 13 13:17:05 raspberrypi rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.4.2" x-pid="486" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
```

So I'm wondering if something related to rsyslogd might be causing this.

FYI: After the freeze the monitor is dark and unresponsive.

I'll be grateful for any help!

marc.

Comment: This appears to be a software and not a hardware issue - so what software are you running - eg what OS etc?

Comment: Adrian, thanks for your question. PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian

Comment: Could this be caused by a defunct python script left over by a fork process?